# Explanation of theorem of natural irrationalities

Tags: field-theory

Let's recall the theorem of natural irrationalities as discussed in abstract algebra texts :

> **Theorem of natural irrationalities**: Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension and let $L/F$ be another extension. Then $KL/L$ is a Galois extension and $[KL:L] = [K:K\cap L] $.

My intuitive understanding of this result is that the procedure used to obtain $K$ from $F$ (namely adjoining roots of a polynomial in $F[x]$ to $F$) can be applied on $L$ to get $KL$. The intersection $K\cap L$ is needed to take care of the fact that if there are some things common in $K$ and $L$ then those things are not needed to be adjoined to $L$ to get $KL$ (which makes sense because those are already in $L$).

The name "natural irrationality" arises in context of the proof of unsolvability of quintic equation by radicals. Crucial to Abel's proof was the following result (in modern notation) :

> **Abel's version of natural irrationalities**: Let $K=\mathbb{C} (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),F=\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$ where $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n$ the are elementary symmetric functions of indeterminates $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$. Let $v\in K$ lie in some radical extension of $F$. Then there is a radical extension $L$ of $F$ with $L\subseteq K$ such that $v\in L$.

In other words while trying to solve the equations via radicals one never needs to go outside the splitting field. The radical extensions which lie between $F$ and $K$ are then considered *natural*. Abel's proof of the theorem uses roots of unity in an essential manner and that's why the field $\mathbb{C} $ is used as the base of $K, F$.

I am somehow not able to map the idea presented in Abel's version with the theorem stated at the beginning of the post. Are these ideas related in some way or is it just a coincidence that the theorems have a similar name?

If they are related it would be great if some details on the link between them is presented.

Comment: Any specific reason for downvotes? If something is not clear please let me know and I can try to update my question.